# How to use spread syntax to return object and overwrite a property that reference to an array

Tags: javascript, react-native, ecmascript-6, redux

```js
let array = [{id: 3, value: 18},{id: 4, value: 20}]

let state = {array, someOtherProperty: [1,2,3]}

function f(){
  return {...state, state.array.find(x=>x.id === 3)['value']: 20}
}

console.log(f())
```

Basically trying to replace the value 18 to 20 where id = 3 and leave alone all other property of `state`. Not sure how to use spread syntax in such case

Expected output as below:

```
state = {
   array: [{id:3, value:20}, {id:4, value: 20}], 
   someOtherProperty: [1,2,3]
}
```

Comment: I don't know what you are trying to do, do you want state to be an array or an object? Is it normal that your state looks like `{ array: [], someOtherProperty: [1, 2, 3]}`

Comment: Can you post the exact output format you are trying to achieve?

Comment: why the need to use spread? You can use `.map` if you don't want to mutate.
`array.map(item => {if(item.id ===3){item.value = 20} return item})`

Comment: @Eddie: I've added my expected output as above

Comment: @AhmedMusallam: Because this is a common pattern in redux reducer where there are bunch of other states that you don't want to mess with. So retrieve one particular state and modify that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could accomplish that by using `map`, the following way:

```js
let array = [{
  id: 3,
  value: 18
}, {
  id: 4,
  value: 20
}]

let state = {
  array,
  someOtherProperty: [1, 2, 3]
}

function f() {
  return { ...state,
    array: array.map(item => item.id === 3 ? { ...item,
      value: 20
    } : item)
  }
}

console.log(f())
```

This way you are using the original array and replacing only the elements that must be changed.